# Add structure to list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, structure

In my example of code I have this:

```
 domains

  room   = symbol.  
  door   = symbol.
  hall   = symbol.

 action     = actionrh(room,hall,door);
             actionhr(hall,room,door).

    listaction  = action*  


 predicates

     addA(action,listaction,listaction)

clauses

addA(X,L2,[X|L2]).

...

addA(actionrh(r(room),p(Hall),X),listaction,listaction)
```

I like make a structure list of action type: [ (room1,hall8,door3), (room34, hall16,door5) ... ]. This is for save a route.
 But when I try add a structure to list this not work.
 Why when I do this it does not work? Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is PDC Prolog or Turbo Prolog? And what is `addA(actionrh(r(room),p(Hall),X),listaction)`? Is it supposed to be a query, a clause declaration, or something that belongs in the `predicates` section? It looks like a mix of things that aren't right. It has some variables and some type names, and only two arguments (`addA` is indicated to have 3 according to the `predicates` section).

Comment: Sorry, I like make a structure list of action type: [ (room1,hall8,door3), (room34, hall16,door5) ... ]. this is for save a route.

Comment: You have to learn some basic things first, like unification and logical variables.  Variables have to start with upper case letters, try `addA(actionrh(r(room),p(Hall),X), [], List)`.

Comment: In the clauses section, you need clauses. You shouldn't be making reference to the "data types" you declared earlier at this point, like `listaction`. @jschimpf has the correct suggestion on what to try.